# Chemical formula: Bond an atom to a bond between other atoms

Tags: chemfig

How to draw this? im having trouble drawing the cycle as it must be connected by the bond,

also anyway to diminish the cycle bond size (`atom sep`) without having to add the sep to each bond?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{
    \chemfig{
                -C(-[90])(-[-90])
                -C(-[90])(-[-90]*6(=-=-=-))
                -C(-[90])(-[-90])
                -C(-[90])(-[-90]*6(=-=-=-))
                -C(-[90])(-[-90])
                -C(-[90])(-[-90]*6(=-=-=-))
            }
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This?

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}    
    \chemfig{-C(-[2])(-[6])-C(-[2])(-[6]*6([:-90,.5]-=-=-=))-C(-[2])(-[6])-C(-[2])(-[6]*6([:-90,.5]-=-=-=))-C(-[2])(-[6])-C(-[2])(-[6]*6([:-90,.5]-=-=-=))-}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want it to be the same as your figure (which is wrong for chemistry) I needed to build a ring "by hand" and adjust the length of each bond one by one

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}    
    \definesubmol{arom}{*6([,.5]-=-=-=)}
    \chemfig{
        -C(-[2])(-[6])
        -C(-[2])(-[6]-[0,.25]=_[:300,.5]-[:240,.5]=_[4,.5]-[:120,.5]=_[:60,.5]-[0,.25])
        -C(-[2])(-[6])
        -C(-[2])(-[6]-[0,.25]=_[:300,.5]-[:240,.5]=_[4,.5]-[:120,.5]=_[:60,.5]-[0,.25])
        -C(-[2])(-[6])
        -C(-[2])(-[6]-[0,.25]=_[:300,.5]-[:240,.5]=_[4,.5]-[:120,.5]=_[:60,.5]-[0,.25])
        -}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this solves for the size, but the bond is still connecting to the atom, pay attention to where the cycle connects with the chain

Comment: If you want a molecule like the one in the figure, it is chemically wrong

Comment: Im quite aware, im just filling a request from a teacher. Thank you never the less

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\definesubmol{mybenz}{-[6,0.7]-[::90,0.2,,,draw=none]*6([::-120,0.4]-=-=-=)}
\begin{document}
        \chemfig{
            -C(-[2])(-[6])
            -C(-[2])(!{mybenz})
            -C(-[2])(-[6])
            -C(-[2])(!{mybenz})
            -C(-[2])(-[6])
            -C(-[2])(!{mybenz})
            -C(-[2])(-[6])-
        }
\end{document}
```

[image]